# Session-scoped bean leaks in wrong ApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring, applicationcontext, session-scope

I have an application, that has 2 ApplicationContexts `A` and `B`, where `A` is the parent context of `B`. `B` overwrites some beans from `A`, but also uses some of its beans. For the frontend, I use Wicket and I have two Wicket applications `AppA` and `AppB` that use the respective Spring ApplicationContext.

The problem now arises with a Session-scoped bean `sessionBean`, for which I have 2 different implementations: `A` defines a factory method returning an instance of `sessionBeanA`, `B` has a factory method with same signature returning an instance of `sessionBeanB`. 
The user now opens `AppB` and in the backend, we get an instance of `sessionBeanB`, wherever we inject a `sessionBean`, as we would expect.
However, if the user now leaves `AppB` and opens `AppA` (still with the same underlying session), we get an instance of `sessionBeanB` injected in `A`, because the `SessionScope` object still holds the previously created bean object.

How can I prevent that a session-scoped bean leaks in a different ApplicationContext? ApplicationContext `A` should not have to bother with beans from `B`...

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to extend the `SessionScope` from Spring to also consider the ApplicationContext by using a `CustomScopeConfigurer` as follows:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomScopeConfigurer;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;

public final class SessionScopeConfigurer extends CustomScopeConfigurer implements ApplicationContextAware {
  private final CustomSessionScope scope;

  public SessionScopeConfigurer() {
    scope = new CustomSessionScope();
    // Overwrite the session scope added by Spring
    addScope("session", scope);
  }

  @Override
  public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    scope.setApplicationContextId(applicationContext.getId());
  }
}
```

where `CustomSessionScope` is:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.ObjectFactory;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.SessionScope;

/**
 * Extends {@link SessionScope} by modifying all bean names, so that they are specific to their ApplicationContext.
 * This avoids session-scoped beans from context a leaking through context b.
 */
public class CustomSessionScope extends SessionScope {
  private String applicationContextId;

  public void setApplicationContextId(String applicationContextId) {
    this.applicationContextId = applicationContextId;
  }

  @Override
  public Object get(String name, ObjectFactory<?> objectFactory) {
    return super.get(modify(name), objectFactory);
  }

  @Override
  public Object remove(String name) {
    return super.remove(modify(name));
  }

  @Override
  public void registerDestructionCallback(String name, Runnable callback) {
    super.registerDestructionCallback(modify(name), callback);
  }

  private String modify(String name) {
    // Attach ApplicationContextId to the bean name
    return name + applicationContextId;
  }
}
```

and you can use it in the Java Spring configuration class with:

```
@Bean
public static CustomScopeConfigurer configureSessionScope() {
  return new SessionScopeConfigurer();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's maybe helpfull to change the scope of the Beans. Reduce the scope to @conversation.

Here you'll find more infomations about the scopes an contextes:

https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/2.4.0.CR1/en-US/html/scopescontexts.html

Comment: The link you provided is about CDI, not Spring dependency injection, so it's not really applicable to my case